# How To Get Reflection List<T> Inherited Class

Tags: c#, system.reflection

How can I find the inherited class in the list property?

```
 public class BaseEntity
    {
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    }

    public class Product : BaseEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Price> Prices { get; set; } = new List<Price>();
    }

    public class Price : BaseEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Product Product { get; set; }
    }
```

In the Product class, I want to get the Price Property by using the Reflection method and see if it has inherited the BaseEntity class.

**My goal is to have a Genecric Extension method so that I can have properties that inherit the Base Entity class.
To set the property for the IsActive field**

Comment: Why would you want to use reflection? And what do you mean by "get the Price property"? You don't have a `Price` property.

Comment: My goal is to be able to find by reflection all the features inherited from the BaseEntity class

Comment: But you can see all the properties of that class, they're written in your code here.

Comment: I have this class in Generic and this section is in a Extenstion Method 

public static IQueryable<TEntity> ApplyActive<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> queryable)